# How to set the specified position of textview in listview adapter?

Tags: android

I am trying to set the position of the textview in the listview and change the value which I get from the button position that I click on listview. Is there a solution to set the position of the textview so  I can change the value of the textview that on the same position with the button that i clicked?

Here is the code when i get the position of the button :

```
        viewHolder.increase.setTag(pos);
        viewHolder.decrease.setTag(pos);
        viewHolder.count.setTag(pos);

        viewHolder.increase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int posisi =(Integer)v.getTag();
                Log.d(TAG, "POSISI TAMBAH : " + posisi);
                countcheckBox++;
                changeCheckBox(posisi);
                produk.hitung();
            }
        });

        viewHolder.decrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int posisi =(Integer)v.getTag();
                Log.d(TAG, "POSISI KURANG : " + posisi);
                if (countcheckBox>0) {
                    countcheckBox--;
                    changeCheckBox(posisi);
                    produk.hitung();
                }
            }
        });
```

And here is the method to change the value :

```
public void changeCheckBox(int posisix){
    Log.d(TAG, "POSISI VALUE : " + posisix);
    viewHolder.count.setSelected(posisix); //here i'm trying to set the position of textview that have the same position with the button
    viewHolder.count.setText(countcheckBox+"");
}
```

Comment: you can simply write if(position==your button position)than set textview else not

Comment: Hello mitesh makwana, actually, in my case now, the position of the button "+" is different with the viewholder.count position, for example: the position of the button "+" that i click is 0, and the viewholder.count position that changes is in 5 position, if the button "+" position is not equal viewholder.count position, then what should I do?